# How is a keygen made by reversing a software?

Tags: ida, disassembly

I know that a software is cracked by reverse engineering it and reading it's assembly code... My question is how and what do crackers look for in the assembly code? And how do they know what algorithm is being used to verify the serial code (since we cannot see the original source code)?

Comment: The assembly code is better than the original source code, it tells you exactly what happens.  What you look for: start looking for the error message which is printed when your license key is wrong, and work back from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are asking for an introduction to reverse engineering. If this is a topic that interests you, I recommend a well known tutorial series from the "Legend of Random". The original blog is now defunct, but is mirrored here:

http://octopuslabs.io/legend/blog/sample-page.html

The tutorials build upon one another, so if you'd like to learn start with #1 and finish them all.

[Tutorial #19](http://octopuslabs.io/legend/blog/archives/1875/1875.htm) addresses your question more directly, but you should complete the other tutorials in order to gain the knowledge necessary to understand tutorial #19.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Mick said, [here is an excellent video tutorial on the topic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DEDYk8zN53A), where the individual takes nearly 2 hours to thoroughly demonstrate how to reverse engineer the key validation algorithm in a particular CrackMe.

While it's a "simple" example in a world filled with much more complex key/license algorithms, I think it's an incredible resource for beginners/intermediates to learn from.